# More wxPython frustration - toolbars

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, toolbar

I'm trying to add a toolbar to a window that can hold 128-pix png's (code below). I can get everything showing, but I just don't seem to be able to change the size of the icons. I've come across a similar post and tried the approach it suggests to overcome the problem but to no avail.

Interestingly deleting the line at the end:

> self.SetToolBar(toolbar)

does increase the size of the icon, but I then lose the nicer formatting gained via the SetToolbar() call. In case it makes a difference, I'm running mac OS-X snow Leopard/python2.7

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,size=(400, 350))

        self.InitUI() 
        self.Centre() 
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self, size=(-1, 128))
        toolbar.SetToolBitmapSize((128,128))


        bmp2 = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_ADD_BOOKMARK, wx.ART_OTHER, (128,128))

        toolbar.AddLabelTool(-1, label="Add", bitmap=bmp2, 
                                         shortHelp="Add", kind=wx.ITEM_NORMAL)

        toolbar.Realize()
        self.SetToolBar(toolbar)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App() 
    Example(None, title='') 
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: On Windows I am getting a BIG icon-button.

Comment: +1 for RUNNABLE wxpython example included with the question.

Comment: Looks like it may be a mac thing then

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Mac thing, you might be able to work around it by creating your own toolbar using a panel, a sizer and a set of BitmapButtons. I would think that that would work for you.